# Search a select list with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to build a search box for a select list, and I'm looking for some suggestions on doing this with jQuery. My goal is to hightlight `<option/>`'s that contain the search string or hide all `<option/>`'s that don't. I thought I was on to something with attribute selectors until I realized that I'm searching on the HTML content and not an attribute.

```
<select name="Users" id="Users">
  <option value="123">Frank Smith (fsmith@example.com)</option>
  <option value="456">Joe Banks (jbanks@example.com)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: There's a plugin that kind of does what you want. Maybe you can use it for inspiration. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/AddIncSearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the contains() selector http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
$("option:contains('Joe')");
```